# Highmaps mapbubble

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I have such a problem. I can't style the bubble when highmaps added to the page by single file(`<script src="Resources/plugins/high-charts/js/highmaps.js"></script>`). All options are ignored. 
[image]

And when I add highmaps via this two files:

```
<script src="Resources/plugins/high-charts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="Resources/plugins/high-charts/js/modules/map.js"></script>
```

I can style bubbles but the regions are all the same color. They don't fill in different colors by their values as you can see on the first picture.[image]

If someone faced with a similar problem?

Comment: Can you make a live example (e.g. on jsfiddle) with the behaviour your describe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue with a strange method. Added random color to the map: `mapOptions.series[0].color = 'rgba(144,237,125,0.8)';`
and regions filled with different colors:
[image]